# Best way to convert/show a date

Tags: php, date, strtotime, getdate

I have a php form which requires the user to input a date. I have three check boxes that they can choose from: "today", "tomorrow", and "other" (where other requires them to enter a specific date in the  field.

I want "today" to print out the current day, "tomorrow" to print out tomorrow's day/date, and "other" to print out the date they choose. The format should be "Day, Month date" (Friday, July 8).

For today's date it's pretty straight forward, just use the getdate() array, but is there a simple way to get tomorrow's date (without requiring multiple steps/error checking)? And is there a simple way to convert the output of  (and is the day of the week stored in the output for type=date)?

Comment: Check out PHP's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Tomorrow: `<? $tomorrow = strotime("+1 day"); ?>`

For any date you'd need to parse it, with `strotime($date_input);`, however be aware that PHP tries to find out the date format, with dates separated by slashes being the american standard (M/D/Y), and dates separated by dashes being international (D-M-Y).

For the weekday, it's a parameter (`l`) to the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function. So to print in the format you wish:

```
echo date('l, F d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: So for the other date field I did this: "$date=strtotime($_POST['pickupDateOther']);" and when I inputted the date (03-14-2017) it shows: "1489464000"

Comment: This is the timestamp of the date, to be passed as the second parameter to `date`. The string in the format you wish is obtained by `$dateFormatted = date('l, F d', $date);`

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that your `$date` already has a `strtotime`. No need to call it again when formatting

Comment: It still prints out a weird number. Is there something I'm forgetting to do?

Comment: `$date=strtotime($_POST['pickupDateOther']); $dateFormatted = date('l, F d', $date); echo $dateFormatted;` ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been busy the last few days and haven't had a chance to work on the site. I have this but nothing is printed. $date = strtotime($_POST['pickupDateOther']); $dateFormatted = date('l, F d', $date); @asiviero

Comment: For some reason $_POST['pickupDateOther'] is empty even when I put a date into the <input type="date" name="pickupDateOther"> field ; @asiviero

Answer (score 0):

```
date('l F\, d', strtotime(' +1 day'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class accepts many types of date inputs like:

```
$string = "today" or "tomorrow" or "1 day" or "10 years"
$date = new DateTime($string);
```

Then you can format the date however you want:

```
$formattedDate = $date->format('l, F jS');
```

That will format the date as: `Friday, July 8th`

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for a full list of possible formats.